# MySQL select all entries in a recurring time interval from a table with a timestamp column

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say i have a table in a MySQL db with the following schema.

```
+-----------+--------+
| timestamp | string |
+-----------+--------+
```

And in this table are many entries per day for a month.

Now i want to count the entries between 6am and 10am per day for every day in the table and group them by this timeframe for each day.

The response should be something like this

```
+------+------------------------------+
| date | count in the given timeframe |
+------+------------------------------+
```

My Problem is how to select a recurring time frame. I know how to count the entries and how to group them.

I had success to do that on an intervall. But the intervall is not the same for every day.

```
 SELECT count(timestamp) as count,
 ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp)/(60 * 60 * ", hours, ")) AS timekey
 FROM event_data,
 GROUP BY timekey
```

Comment: What have you already tried? [See this article on how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - For a tip I'd suggest first looking at aggregate functions such as `COUNT`

Comment: The counting part is not the problem, i know about count(entry) and GROUP BY. The part i dont know is how to select a recurring time frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you are working on MySQL, you can use the following query:

```
SELECT 
    date(timestamp1) AS entrydate
    , COUNT(*) FROM mytable
WHERE 
    EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIME(timestamp1)) BETWEEN 6 AND 10
GROUP BY 
    entrydate
```

Where

- timestamp1 --> timestamp in your example
- entrydate --> date in your desired output column
- mytable --> the table which holds the data

And, please provide some sample entries next time and try to be a bit specific.

Comment: This is almost the query i need, except one problem. I need the result to contain the count for every available day in the table not only one specific date.

Answer (score 1):

`psuedo code` will be like

```
select timestamp ,
       sum(case when hours of timestamp between 6am and 10am then 1 else 0 end) timeframe_count
from yourtable
group by timestamp
```